# HTML form to Update Database - Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'x' cannot be null

Tags: php, mysql

I know similar questions have been asked, but despite research, I've been unable to figure out how to remedy my current issue (and I'm very new at this so my apologies if this is an easy question or worded awkwardly).

```
"Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'ProdName' cannot be null"
```

I am trying to do a simple post from an html form to a test table in my database.

I originally thought I had remedied the error because for about three posts, I was able to update my MySQL database without getting the error. Then, without changing anything, I started to have to same error occur again.

This is my php, there is a simple html form in a separate file with method="post" set.

```
<?php
$dsn = 'mysql: host=localhost; dbname=test';
$user = 'user';
$password = 'xxxx';
try {
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
$pdo ->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$ProdName = $_POST[ 'ProdName' ];

  $stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO testtable (ProdName) VALUES(:ProdName)');
  $stmt->execute(array(
    ':ProdName' => $ProdName)
  );

  # Affected Rows?
  echo $stmt->rowCount(); // 
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

?>
```

I have a very simple table right now, with ID and ProdName as columns. ID is set as the primary key and to auto increment. I have no problems connecting to my db at least...

**What do I need to do to remedy the error so my code performs properly?**

(Again, new at this and really wanting to learn from this experience as much as possible).

**Any idea why it might have worked for a bit then thrown the error again?**

**Edit:**

Here is the html:

```
<html>
<form action="form.php" method="post">
    <h3>Product Name:</h3>
    <input type="text" name="ProdName">
    <input type="submit">
</html>
```

Comment: Can you post the front-end code?

Comment: did my answer help you or not?

Comment: Yes it does!!! Thank you! I've marked your answer as the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that `$_POST['ProdName']` is empty. Try wrapping this around your code:

```
if(!empty($_POST['ProdName'])){
    //the PDO query
}

//if $_POST['ProdName'] is empty, you can add an else statement which displays an error message

else{
    echo 'The product name field can\'t be empty!';
}
```

Comment: Please forgive my ignorance, but how/where should I wrap it exactly? (I'm trying this solution now, and hope to try it...correctly).

Comment: @User2577 if the query shown in your code is the only query, I'd wrap it around it *all* your code if I were you